# In leScanCallback device.getName() returns null on few devices

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-bluetooth

Checked following post but not helpful on my case :

[BluetoothDevice always returns null on getName()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792785/4111151)

**My problem**

I am developing an application that scans the nearby Bluetooth device and displays in the home screen.But on few devices(i.e moto G,samsung note2) the device name is null on leScanCallback.

**My code**

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi,
                         byte[] scanRecord) {
       if (device.getName() != null){//<<- Here it null on few device
           //my process          
        }
  }
};
```

**Note:**
I need to throw an alert if it return null but i can't do it inside the onlescan because the scanning continuously. Before that i need to throw alert to user based on the bluetooth version is it possible and why on few devices i wont get the device name ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The name field is not populated on the first detections of the advertisement because it comes from a separate ScanResponse packet, which does not arrive until later than the advertisement callback you get.

This means you must hold a reference to the `BluetoothDevice` object returned by the scan and wait a few seconds to see if the name is populated.

Comment: how to keep the Bluetooth device in reference? i keep all the devices that i got in lescan in hashmap.

Comment: Sure, keeping all the devices you detected in a HashMap would work.

Comment: but if the device name is null unless i restart the app the name didn't change.